# Identify this indoor plant

Tags: identification, indoors

Can anyone ID this indoor plant growing in the UK?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a zz plant, *Zamioculcas zamiifolia* in Latin. It is a very common houseplant with easy [care](https://plantcaretoday.com/zamioculcas-zamiifolia-zz-plant.html) instructions.